# i am getting this error while using && in if

Tags: java

```
Solution.java:30: error: illegal character: '\u202c'
                if(x>=-2147483648‬ && x<=2147483647)
                                 ^
Solution.java:30: error: not a statement
                if(x>=-2147483648‬ && x<=2147483647)
                                   ^
Solution.java:30: error: ';' expected
                if(x>=-2147483648‬ && x<=2147483647)
                                                   ^
Solution.java:34: error: illegal character: '\u202c'
                if(x>=-(pow(2,61))‬ && x<=pow(2,61)-1)
                                  ^
Solution.java:34: error: not a statement
                if(x>=-(pow(2,61))‬ && x<=pow(2,61)-1)
                                    ^
Solution.java:34: error: ';' expected
                if(x>=-(pow(2,61))‬ && x<=pow(2,61)-1)
                                                     ^
6 errors
```

Comment: You have special characters in your code. Just use normal ASCII.

Comment: `if (x >= Integer.MIN_VALUE && x <= Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: `\ u202c`  is POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING, which is a weird character to have in your code. Try deleting the whole line and retyping it character by character.

Comment: Hint: this kind of thing can happen if you copy-and-paste code from a formatted document.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have pointed out, there is an extra character in there before the first space before the first ampersand. Here is how you could use java to tell.

```
public static void printStringDetails(String s) {
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i) + " " + (int)(s.charAt(i)));
}
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "if(x>=-2147483648‬ && x<=2147483647)";
    printStringDetails(s);
    s = "if(x>=-(pow(2,61))‬ && x<=pow(2,61)-1)";
    printStringDetails(s);
}
```

where I pasted your strings in.
Output is:

```
i 105
f 102
( 40
x 120
> 62
= 61
- 45
2 50
1 49
4 52
7 55
4 52
8 56
3 51
6 54
4 52
8 56
‬ 8236
  32
& 38
& 38
  32
x 120
< 60
= 61
2 50
1 49
4 52
7 55
4 52
8 56
3 51
6 54
4 52
7 55
) 41
i 105
f 102
( 40
x 120
> 62
= 61
- 45
( 40
p 112
o 111
w 119
( 40
2 50
, 44
6 54
1 49
) 41
) 41
‬ 8236
  32
& 38
& 38
  32
x 120
< 60
= 61
p 112
o 111
w 119
( 40
2 50
, 44
6 54
1 49
) 41
- 45
1 49
) 41
```

Notice the two occurrences of 8236 before the space (ASCII 32) before the first ampersand in each line.
Then you can go back in and edit so that the output is what you expect. Thus:

```
if(x>=-2147483648 && x<=2147483647)
```

(paste that between the quotes and you will see I deleted the unwanted character)
and

```
if(x>=-(pow(2,61)) && x<=pow(2,61)-1)
```

should fix it.

Comment: Or just copy/paste the text into https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Unicode#explorer

Comment: I did not know that existed. Cool. Thanks for the reference.